# java mock private function which include public function

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

How to mock a private function when it includes public function?

I tried PowerMockito and it always says the child public function wrong return type.

I should test the public function, and it contains private function, and that private function also contains another public function.

Appreciate for your help.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
@PrepareForTest(TokenServiceImpl.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
class TokenServiceImplTest {
    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    TokenServiceImpl tokenService;

    @Mock
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Test
    void getCachedTokenIfCacheTokenNotEmpty() throws Exception {
        // given
        String accessToken = "accessToken";
        String digest = "digest";
        String cacheToken = "cacheToken";
        // when
//        Mockito.when(tokenService.checkJWTToken(cacheToken)).thenReturn(true);
//        Mockito.when(jwtDecoder.decode(cacheToken)).thenReturn(null);
        PowerMockito.when(tokenService, "getAccessToken", digest).thenReturn(cacheToken);
        // then
        String result = tokenService.getCachedToken(accessToken, digest);
        assertEquals(cacheToken, result);
    }
}
```

```
public class TokenServiceImpl implements TokenService {
    @Autowired
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;
    @Autowired
    TokenRepository tokenRepository;
  public String getCachedToken(String accessToken, String digest) {
        String cachedToken = getAccessToken(digest);
        return cacheToken;
  }
@Override
    public Boolean checkJWTToken(String jwtToken) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(jwtToken)) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            jwtDecoder.decode(jwtToken);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("token invalid: ", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
   private String getAccessToken(String key) {
        String token = tokenRepository.getAccessToken(key);
        return checkJWTToken(token) ? token : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't test private methods. Test API.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- sry, i am not so clear what you mean to, can you say more detail?

Comment: Don't try to mock `getAccessToken`, that's part of the class you are trying to test. Just mock the results of `tokenRepository.getAccessToken()` and `jwtDecoder.decode(jwtToken)`, if you want a test where that throws an exception.

Comment: oh.. amazing. it works!! I am very appreciated , may I know why it works after I only mock the results of ```tokenRepository.getAccessToken()``` and ```jwtDecoder.decode(jwtToken)```